# Contrl room not accessible after connecting to vpn

Tags: automationanywhere

I have installed control room and client successfully and also able to work on it. But, whenever I connect VPN, the control room disconnects automatically with the message "The requested address could not be resolved".
It seems that the control room binds with the system IP, and when connected over VPN system IP changes. As per my understanding, this could be the reason for the disconnection of Control Room over VPN.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?
Please let me know if you have a solution for this or let me know where can I get help with this issue

Comment: The obvious solution would be to setup a VPN connection for the AAE Client as well. That way they are both on the same network. Alternatively, open the AAE Client's system to the ' public internet' as described here for instance: https://www.nch.com.au/kb/10046.html . Note that you are now sending potentially sensitive data over the internet, so tread carefully. The former option has my preference.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is correct. and this is not an error.

Once the machine is connected to the VPN, then it is effectively on the remote network... so all local resources (including the control room) will not be reachable. most likely you are connecting to the control room using its FQDN.

so you can do one of these things:

- while connecting the AA client to the control room, use its IP address instead of hostname
- use split DNS on ur VPN or split tunneling